# Need help shortning my VBA code and making it loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

So I have some data that I will need to run my macro on monthly. My code works for what I need it for but I thought this might be a good chance for me to try and learn how to loop something that's so repetitive as I'm still pretty new to all this. So below is my code and basically all it does is copy all contents in column A and another specified column, pastes them in a new sheet, renames the sheet after a certain cell on Sheet1 and deletes any blank rows that contains a blank cell. I just simply copied and pasted the original recorded macro and made some changes to make it do the whole sheet.

I would to try and learn how to slim it down and loop rather than having to copy and paste it. This is more of a learning thing for me as this macro already works for what I need.

Thanks a lot!

```
Sub test()
'
'     test Macro
'

'
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A:A,B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



Range("A:A,C:C").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("C1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



Range("A:A,D:D").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("D1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



Range("A:A,E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,F:F").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("F1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,G:G").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("G1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,H:H").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("H1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,I:I").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("I1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,J:J").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("J1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,K:K").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("K1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,L:L").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("L1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,M:M").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("M1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate



    Range("A:A,N:N").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheet1.Range("N1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate






End Sub
```

Comment: What loops have you tried? (for, while, do while)?

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
Sub test()

Dim CurrentColumn As String 'define a variable

For i = 1 To 13 'loop over the letter B to N (13 values if I counted right)
    CurrentColumn = Chr(65 + i) 'Here you play with ascii table 65 is the code for A, 66 for B, etc.

    Range("A:A," & CurrentColumn & ":" & CurrentColumn).Select 'replace in the string the fix value by our variable
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(CurrentColumn & "1").Value 'same here
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Next

End Sub
```

Exemple of the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Tell me if you need more details than what is in the comments

Comment: `CurrentColumn = Chr(65 + i) `  Nice, I was trying to firgure out how to work through iterating through the columns, I didnt realize you could do this through the ascii.

Comment: This actually works perfect! I can see that the    CurrentColumn = Chr(65 + i)    will come in handy in some future macros so thanks for sharing that. Also the use of    Next    seems so simple so I'm not too sure how I couldn't figure that one out on my own but your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tensibai Actually now it doesn't seem to want to change the sheet names. Runs the rest of the macro fine but wont actually change the sheet names. Is there any other way of pulling the names from Sheet1?

Comment: @xcallmeclayx Sorry for the long answer, I suspect the Sheet1.Range not being set here, (I assumed it was defined elsewhere in your code to reference sheet1, replace it with `Sheets("Sheet1").Range` and it should work. (Editing in this way)

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a sub-procedure...
Try this out:

```
Sub test()

Dim SecondColumnIndexNumber As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For SecondColumnIndexNumber = 2 To 13
        DoTheMove (SecondColumnIndexNumber)
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub DoTheMove(SecondColumnIndexNumber As Integer)
' This takes a number as the input for the second column that will be copied over
' For example 2 corresponds to copying over columns A (always the case) and column B - Range("A:A,B:B")
' For example 4 corresponds to copying over columns A (always the case) and column D - Range("A:A,D:D")

Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Dim SecondColumn As Range
Dim RangeToCopy As Range

Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Set SecondColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(SecondColumnIndexNumber)
Set RangeToCopy = Union(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), SecondColumn)

    NewSheet.Activate
    RangeToCopy.Copy NewSheet.Range("A1")
    On Error Resume Next
    NewSheet.Range("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    NewSheet.Name = Sheet1.Cells(1, SecondColumn).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This seems to work but when it doesn't seem to rename the sheets. I'm actually having the same problem with the other edits submitted above. If I use my original code, it works just fine..

Comment: @xcallmeclayx, So long as the name is in the first row of the column moved, it should work just as well as your macro did....